# How to iterate over a set of unequal integers in order?

Tags: python, loops, integer

In the following example, the How to iterate over a list of integers?

```
index_set = {2, 4, 5*5, 10*5, 15*5, 20*5, 30*5, 40*5, 45*5}
for index in index_set:
      ...
      print(index, end=',')
      ...
```

Output

```
225,2,4,100,200,75,50,150,25,
```

Desired output

```
2,4,25,50,75,100,150,200,225
```

Some answers change the question to how to print a set of numbers in order and remove the loop.  There is additional processing besides the display of the integer in the loop.

I believe the simplest answer is to change from a set to a list so order is kept.

Comment: I'm not familiar with python.  The goal is to have the numbers come out in order.  Are you suggesting to use square brackets?

Comment: just sort the set when iterating over it.

Comment: Your question is "how to iterate over a list of integers", but that's not a list, that's a set. Sets have arbitrary order. If you wanted a list, you would use square brackets `[ ]` instead of curly braces `{ }`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No need for the loop:

```
index_set = {2, 4, 5*5, 10*5, 15*5, 20*5, 30*5, 40*5, 45*5}
index_set = ", ".join([str(i) for i in sorted(index_set)])
print(index_set)
```

Output:

```
2, 4, 25, 50, 75, 100, 150, 200, 225
```

Comment: this is just sorting the set, it is not " sort the set into a list"

Comment: Yes, this is what I was looking for.  I'm doing more than printing the indices.  I'm trying to output, or process, select values.  Thank you.

Comment: @John you have to wait 15 minutes I believe.

Comment: But, I need the loop, I'm processing data, and need the process the right indices...

Answer (score 0):

if you just want to sort it you can use `list` comprehension:

```
print(sorted([x for x in index_set]))
```

or convert it directly into a `list`:

```
print(sorted(list(index_set)))
```

output:

```
[2, 4, 25, 50, 75, 100, 150, 200, 225]
```

or, using a similar approach as you did:

```
for index in sorted(index_set):
  print(index,end=', ')
```

output:

```
2, 4, 25, 50, 75, 100, 150, 200, 225
```

Comment: if you/OP wants list - `print(list(sorted(index_set))`

Comment: yes, its the same, i just wanted to use list comprehension

Answer (score 0):

try wrapping your index_set with the sorted function:

```
for index in sorted(index_set):
      print(index, end=', ')
```